# Promise will not resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

The second part of the Promise below (inside the `then`) is never run. When I run the database query without using the Promise(in a node script that I run `node myscript.js` it returns the data but the console never returns the prompt--the console just hangs and I have to send an interrupt manually. Therefore, when I put it inside a Promise, I think the Promise doesn't know that the database query is complete even though it seems to have returned all the data, therefore the second part of the Promise isn't running ( I think). If that's the problem, how do I write the database query so that it doesn't hang and the Promise can run to completion?

```
const sqlite = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sqlite3');
const express = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express')
const promise = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/promise')

app.get('/', (request, res) => {

  var res = [];

  function getData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      db.each('SELECT column_a, column_b FROM trips group by column_a', (e, rows) => {

        var d = {
          a: rows['column_a'],
          b: rows['column_b']
        }


        res.push(d)
      });
    });

  }
  getData().then(function(data) {
    console.log("never run....", res, data) //never run
  });

})
```

Comment: I would recommend using a promise-based library like `node-sqlite` or `q-sqlite3` (which is a promise wrapper around `sqlite3`) instead of manually wrapping all your function calls. It would save a huge amount of typing and maintenance.

Comment: can you link to the node-sqlite library you are referring to?``` npm install -g node-sqlite``` says `Registry returned 404 for GET on http://registry.npmjs.org/node-sqlite`

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite Looking at it again it's just a promise wrapper around sqlite3 (similar to q-sqlite3, but uses native promises).

Comment: Always promisify at the lowest level possible. ie promisify `db.each()`, not `getData()`. This will give you a reusable utility and allow for clearer, cleaner application code.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 can you show to promisify `db.each`?

Comment: @Leahcim, OK, I have given it a go - see answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to resolve a promise by calling one of the functions it provides in the callback through its constructor.

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // you must call resolve() or reject() here
  // otherwise the promise never resolves
});
```

Otherwise it will always stay in *Pending* state and never call the callbacks(s) you pass into `then`.

```
promise.then(() => {
  // this never gets called if we don't resolve() or reject()
});
```

Additionally, promises allow you to resolve with values so there's usually no need to maintain global variables, you can just pass results through.

Finally, the callback in `db.each` will be called **once for each row**, so you would need to handle that by resolving the promise **after all rows have been obtained**

Here's how you could write your code:

```
function getData() {
  const data = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.each('SELECT column_a, column_b FROM trips group by column_a', (e, row) => {
      if (e) {
        // error reading a row, reject the Promise immediately
        // optionally you could accumulate errors here in a similar manner to rows
        reject(e); 
        return;
      } 

      // success reading a row, store the row result
      data.push({
        a: row['column_a'],
        b: row['column_b']
      });

    }, (e, rowCount) => { // the complete handler called when the operation is done, see docs: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete

      if (e) { 
        // operation finished, there was an error
        reject(e);
        return;
      }

      // operation succeeded, resolve with rows
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

app.get('/', (request, res) => {  

  getData().then((data) => {
    // here `data` is an array of row objects
  }, (e) => {
    console.error(`Database error: ${e}`);
  });
});
```

**Side Note**

Not sure why you are redeclaring the parameter `res` as an `[]`, but there's no need for doing `var res = []`. Since you already have `res`, you can just say `res = []` to point `res` to a new array. Of course that will overwrite the response object so I assume that you're doing it just for the purposes of this example. If not, you should probably create a new variable.

Comment: There's more to a full fix than you show because you don't want to be calling `resolve()` inside the `db.each()` as that will call it multiple times and only the first time will actually do anything.

Comment: you're absolutely correct. I didn't consider what the promise was wrapped in, let me fix it.

Comment: @jfriend00 should be fixed now

Comment: Now, it's really messed up.  Your promises array will be empty when you call `Promise.all()` because the callbacks haven't happened yet.  You need to create actual promises that get resolved only when the callback happens and put those in the array.

Comment: Is there a way to know the last row was reached? I'm not familiar with this library. If not, then the only way to estimate that the reading process is done is to create a Promise that will timeout after some time.

Comment: Figured it out from the [docs](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseeachsql-param--callback-complete). The `.each` method also accepts a `complete` handler.

Comment: I gave you an upvote (thank you) but the code unfortunately doesn't work. The code inside your `then` never gets run.... i.e. where you do `res.push(data)`. In my code, I do `res.send(data)` (to send it back to the client) but it doesn't get run. At the point where you call resolve(data) it is an array of all the rows (so that's great) but unfortunately the call to resolve is not passing the data to the `then` clause (as an aside, you are correct, there's no need to redeclare the res, in fact it's harmful to. I need to use  `res` to send the data to client)

Comment: One suggestion.  You're pushing errors into the `data` array.  You can probably just reject on the first error.

Comment: @jfriend00, yeah, I though of that, the reason I'm doing it is because maybe the user still wants some partial results even if one of the rows failed. Also the `complete` handler passes an error if the whole operation failed so that's where I reject the entire Promise. I guess I could resolve with `errors` and with `data`. That might make more sense. Then again I could be just overcomplicating things :)

Comment: @Leahcim are you sure the `then` code isn't running? As you've said, the `resolve` method gets called with the rows and the Node internals are in charge of dispatching that to all promises that have a `then` callback listening for it. So either your Node is broken or you're missing something :)

Comment: I'm absolutely sure the `then` code isn't running (i.e. which I assume means the `resolve` method is not running. To test this out, I rewrote your code to put the promise inside `app.get('/', (request, res)` with the change that I now call `res.send(data)` (instead of `resolve(data)`) to send the data to the client, effectively bypassing the `then` clause which didn't work. my changes work (i.e. I can send the data (i.e. all the rows) to the client) but only if I don't use the `resolve/then`, so I can't accept your answer til I figure out what's wrong but I gave u an upvote.

Comment: Hi @Leahcim, here's a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xt4ojsys/) with a running example, hopefully that helps you figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a Promise which means you're responsible for calling one of `resolve` or `reject` *once and once only*.

Here's a cleaned up example:

```
app.get('/', (request, res) => {  
  var res = [ ];

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.each('SELECT column_a, column_b FROM trips group by column_a', (e, row) => {
      if (e) {
        reject(e);

        return;
      }

      res.push({
          a: row['column_a'],
          b: row['column_b']
      });
    }, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }

      resolve(res);
    });
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log("Running ", res, data)//never run
  }
});
```

If your database layer supports promises that usually makes this sort of code a lot less messy since you can simply chain that in there.

**Edit:** Since the Sqlite3 API is bizarrely non-standard and the [`each` function](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API) has two callbacks you need to handle each `row` with the first, then the completion handler with the second.

If you design an API like this you're doing it wrong. Don't.

Comment: calling resolve() or reject() multiple times is ignored so the responsibility you mention in the first line doesn't matter much :)

Comment: @nem035 Calling it multiple times may be ignored, but that doesn't mean it should be done. Likewise, calling it zero times is a serious problem. There's a difference here between what you're theoretically permitted to do and what you should be doing.

Comment: You're right, can't argue with that. All I meant to say was that we don't really *have to* call the callbacks once, but yes, we definitely should.

Comment: I've tried your code but it's not working as intended. In the demo I tried, there should be about 50 rows, but only 1 row is getting pushed to `res` (and then returned to client in the `then`). Therefore, (inside the callback of the db query) I tried doing ```rows.map(function(rows_, b){  res.push({ rows_['column_a'], ``` etc, but the `rows` returned from the db doens't have a map function.

Comment: This code has the same issue as my prior answer. As **jfriend00** mentioned in a comment to my answer, *"There's more to a full fix than you show because you don't want to be calling resolve() inside the db.each() as that will call it multiple times and only the first time will actually do anything."*

Comment: I've made an edit that uses `rows.forEach`. A function like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) should be available if `rows` is an array. If it isn't you'll need a different strategy here.

Comment: This code is just wrong.  `db.each()` is asynchronous, thus you are calling `resolve(res)` BEFORE any of the rows have been processed and `res` will always be empty.  nem035 has figured out how to do it correctly in their answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 While correcting one syntax error, the closing brackets for the async call weren't there, I made another. Corrected.

Comment: @nem035 Does `each` in this case get called multiple times each time with one row, which is super annoying, or one time with multiple rows?

Comment: @tadman unfortunately, it gets called once for each row :/. It also has an additional parameter which is a callback that gets called after all rows are read but with the number of rows read, not the rows themselves.

Comment: This still doesn't work.  `db.each()` can call its callback multiple times.

Comment: @jfriend00 Updated *again* because this Sqlite library is non-standard and, I'd assert, not worth using. [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) is a significantly better option for interfacing with these sorts of databases because it makes sense *and* you can use promises if you want.

Comment: Probably should have error handling on the completion callback.  But, at least now you're on the right track.

Comment: By popular demand, now with error handling. This is why a single callback method vastly simplifies things, especially if you can wrap it in a Promise neatly.

Answer (score 1):

Several points :

- `resolve`/`reject` must be called, otherwise a `new Promise()` will remain forever "pending".
- always promisify at the lowest level possible, ie promisify `db.each()` not `getData()`. This gives you a testable, reusable utility and more comprehensible application code.
- `db.each()` is a challenge to promisify because it has two possible sources of error; one in its iteration callback and one in its complete callback.
- the sqlite3 documentation does not state what happens if an iteration error occurs but presumably the iteration continues, otherwise the error would simply appear as a completion error?

Here's a couple of ways to promisify :

**1. First iteration error or completion error causes promise rejection - iteration errors are not exposed to your application code.**

```
// Promisification
db.eachAsync = function(sql, iterationCallback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.each(sql, (iterationError, row) => {
            if(iterationError) {
                reject(iterationError);
            } else {
                iterationCallback(row);
            }
        }, (completionError, n) => {
            if(completionError) {
                reject(completionError);
            } else {
                resolve(n); // the number of retrieved rows.
            }
        });
    });
};

// Application
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    function getData() {
        var res = [];
        return db.eachAsync('SELECT column_a, column_b FROM trips group by column_a', (row) => {
            res.push({
                a: row['column_a'],
                b: row['column_b']
            });
        }).then(n => res);
    }
    getData().then(results => {
        console.log(results);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

**2. Only a completion error causes promise rejection - iteration errors are exposed to your application code**

```
// Promisification
db.eachAsync = function(sql, iterationCallback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.each(sql, iterationCallback, (completionError, n) => {
            if(completionError) {
                reject(completionError);
            } else {
                resolve(n); // the number of retrieved rows.
            }
        });
    });
};

// Application
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    function getData() {
        var res = [];
        return db.eachAsync('SELECT column_a, column_b FROM trips group by column_a', (iterationError, row) => {
            // You can choose what to do on iterationError.
            // Here, nulls are injected in place of values from the db,
            // but you might choose not to push anything.
            res.push({
                a: iterationError ? null : row['column_a'],
                b: iterationError ? null : row['column_b']
            });
        }).then(n => res);
    }
    getData().then(results => {
        console.log(results);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

(2) is the better approach because exposing iteration errors affords you more flexibility. For example, you could choose to promisify with (2), and emulate (1) in your application :

```
// Application
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    function getData() {
        var res = [];
        var e = null;
        return db.eachAsync('SELECT column_a, column_b FROM trips group by column_a', (iterationError, row) => {
            if(iterationError && !e) {
                // remember the first iteration error
                e = iterationError; 
            } else {
                // push only on success
                res.push({
                    a: row['column_a'],
                    b: row['column_b']
                });
            }
        }).then(n => {
            if(e) {
                throw e;
            } else {
                return res;
            }
        });
    }
    getData().then(results => {
        console.log(results);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

With (1), by rejecting on first iteration error rather than exposing iteration errors, the same flexibility is not available. (1) could not fully emulate (2).

Fortunately, the preferred approach (2) is the same as would be obtained with Bluebird's `.promisify()` method :

```
Promise.promisify(db.each);
```