# While loop with an async setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, while-loop, settimeout

I have a problem. My code doesn't work. It doesn't display the last essage in the console.log (the "end"). I use a setTimeout promise to do one thing every 3000ms. Here is my promise function setTimeOut

```
function delay(message){
    return new Promise(() => setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(message)
    }, 3000))
}
```

That I use in an async function in my code :

```
async () => {
    while (true) {
        console.log("Start")
        await delay("No")
        console.log("End")
    }
}
```

I make my code more easier (without all the conditions and the functions that I have to call) because I think I've missed something in my understanding of the promise maybe. What am i doing wrong?

Could you please help me for this?

Comment: Where’s the definition of `timeout` and where is `delay` used? You forgot to resolve the promise in `delay`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise will not resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580345/promise-will-not-resolve)

Comment: Sorry, I changed the name of the function to post it, but timeout and delay are the same function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your promise in `delay`/`timeout` function never resolves.

Here's how it will work. Note the `resolve` parameter of the promise callback.

```js
function delay(message) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(message);
        resolve();
    }, 3000))
}
    
(async () => {
    while (true) {
        console.log("Start")
        await delay("No")
        console.log("End")
    }
})();
```

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank you for your help. I misuse the promise, now I'm starting to understand how it works.

Comment: I just had an issue with an while + async function use. Doing a DOM manipulation and checking the result repeatedly in `while` gives incorrect results. Probably due to the render time. I solved the issue with a recursive approach, but this is more practical. Adding a delay after the modification works.