# function keeps returning "Promise { undefined }" while using sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node-sqlite3

I have a function that is called by using

`console.log(getGuildChance(message.guild.id));`

and it keeps returning `Promise { undefined }`, here is the function:

```
async function getGuildChance(guildId) {
    let db = new sqlite.Database('./servers.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite.OPEN_CREATE)
    let query = `SELECT * FROM servers WHERE serverid = ?`;
    db.get(query, [guildId], (err, row) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return;
        }
        return row.chance;
    });
}
```

im a bit lost on what to do, ive already tried using promises but i cant seem to get it. please help and thank you in advance

Comment: put `return` before `db.get(...)`. And this function doesn't need to be marked as `async`, assuming `db.get` returns a Promise.

Comment: @RobinZigmond It doesn't appear to return a promise

Comment: See the canonical question on how to create promises, also [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39580345/1048572) [two questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111106/nodejs-sqlite3-db-run-as-a-bluebird-promise) have specific examples with `sqlite`. If that doesn't help, please [edit] your question to include the code of your attempts at using promises.